# C# Service installer - Upgrade install not stopping service before uninstall

Tags: c#, service, installshield

Please review the code below for my project installer BeforeInstall event. The event is being called, as the install completes successfully and will uninstall my service, before installing the new one, but ONLY if I stop the running service before running the installer for the new version.

For some reason, the code in the event is either not stopping the service, or it is not waiting for the service to stop, both of which I am telling it to do before going on to uninstall the service - which again, will complete successfully if the service is not running. It does not appear to even stop the service because after I get the error that resources are in use, I look in services and see that the service is indeed still running. For reference I have also included the AfterInstall event which successfully starts my service.

[EDIT]
It seems like the check to see if the resources are in use is occurring before my event fires. Actually, I've since tried multiple events from the installer and service installer to no avail. Such as OnBeforeUninstall... etc... I've tried multiple methods of shutting down the process including opening cmd.exe and running sc stop on my service. It does not even attempt to run cmd.exe before it checks if resources are in use. Is there a better place to run the service stop code before the resource check happens? I've even thrown it in before Initialize component on the project installer class. Does anyone know when the resource check happens?

```
void ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ServiceController> services = new List<ServiceController>(ServiceController.GetServices());

        foreach (ServiceController s in services)
        {
            if (s.ServiceName == this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName)
            {
                if(s.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    s.Stop();
                    s.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                }

                ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
                ServiceInstallerObj.Context = new InstallContext();
                ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
                ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = s.ServiceName;
                ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

private void ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ServiceController s = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
        {
            s.Start();
        }
    }
```